# need javascript cross browser solution?

Tags: javascript

here i am giving my javascript which is working fine for IE but not working properly in FireFox. so please tell me what to change in my javascript to run it properly in firefox too.

here is my code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >  
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">  
        <title>Untitled Page</title>  
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

            var modalWindow = null;
            function drawDiv() 
            {
                var txt = document.getElementById('TextBox1');
                var dime = new Dimension(txt);
                modalWindow = document.createElement('div');
                modalWindow.style.position = 'absolute';
                modalWindow.setAttribute("align", "center");
                modalWindow.setAttribute("vertical-align", "middle");
                modalWindow.innerHTML = '<p>hello...</p>';
                modalWindow.style.left = dime.x;
                modalWindow.style.top = dime.y;
                modalWindow.style.width = dime.w;
                modalWindow.style.height = dime.h;
                modalWindow.style.backgroundColor = '#C0C0C0';
                document.body.appendChild(modalWindow);
                return false;
            }

            function hider(whichDiv) 
            {
                document.getElementById(modalWindow).style.display = 'none';
            }

            function Dimension(element) 
            {
                this.x = -1;
                this.y = -1;
                this.w = 0;
                this.h = 0;
                if (element == document) 
                {
                    this.x = element.body.scrollLeft;
                    this.y = element.body.scrollTop;
                    this.w = element.body.clientWidth;
                    this.h = element.body.clientHeight;
                }
                else if (element != null) 
                {
                    var e = element;
                    var left = e.offsetLeft;
                    while ((e = e.offsetParent) != null) 
                    {
                        left += e.offsetLeft;
                    }
                    var e = element;
                    var top = e.offsetTop;
                    while ((e = e.offsetParent) != null) 
                    {
                        top += e.offsetTop;
                    }
                    this.x = left;
                    this.y = top;
                    this.w = element.offsetWidth;
                    this.h = element.offsetHeight;
                }
            }
       </script>  
   </head>  
   <body>  
<div>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="180px" Style="left: 307px; position: relative;  
       top: 264px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="432px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  
        Text="Button" OnClientClick=" return drawDiv()"  />  
</form>
</div> 
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Aaah! My eyes are bleeding! Would you mind using proper code formatting please? Thanks. :)

Comment: Go to [JSBeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and update your code with the properly formatted output from the site. Please?

Comment: Can you please explain the expected behavior, and as much information about the actual _problem_ as possible? E.g. "The box isn't perfectly square" or "Nothing happens when I click the button".

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202914/div-position-problem-generated-dynamically-from-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
            modalWindow.style.left = dime.x + "px";
            modalWindow.style.top = dime.y + "px";
            modalWindow.style.width = dime.w + "px";
            modalWindow.style.height = dime.h + "px";
```

i mean put "px" after dimensions.. otherwise firefox will not understand your unit type :))

Comment: thanks for your answer. i will try this code to solve my problem.